# Airflow Scheduler Keep Failing - SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac #32130

Tags: postgresql, ssl, airflow, psycopg2

Hello can you help me with this error?

I keep writing airflow scheduler -D but it keeps getting failing and giving heartbeat error . :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac

airflow scheduler -D
```

need a permanent solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not an airflow problem. Your code cannot set up connection with postgresql database. Share more details please, how does it work now. I mean database connection process.

Comment: Its running from directly airflow package, I will try deactivating ssl check on postgres config.

2023-05-26 02:30:02,680 ERROR - Exception when executing SchedulerJob._run_scheduler_loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac